# prepopulating ArrayList with massive data set in java

Tags: java, optimization, arraylist

I am trying to make a game where the player can only see in a small radius around them. i'm attempting to do this by covering a 500X500 display with 1X1 black pixels that i can set active or inactive. The problem is that using a standered for loop to add them takes a large amount of time when the program launches and it slows the entire thing down. Any Solutions?

the pix object takes two paramaters(int x, int y)

***code***

```
public ArrayList<Pix> pixs= new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i<=500; i++)
{
    for(int ii = 0; ii<=500; ii++)
    {
        pixs.add(new Pix(ii,i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the slow down is this looping and not how it's being processed? You can also try partitioning the loop and running several parts in parallel.

Comment: Don't bad-mouth for loops. (Do you mean "standard" rather than "slandered"?)

Comment: What does your Pix class look like. You are constructing 250000 instances of PIx so that might take some time. Depending on what the class looks like you might be able to do it with primitives instead.

Comment: For example if all your Pix class contains in 2 ints, the x and y, Consider having a 2 dimensional array of booleans instead. e.g. boolean[][] pixs = new boolean[500][500];

Comment: Side Note (although it will probably be negligable compared to constructing all the instances): as you know the size of you list in advance, you can initialize it with the appropriate capacity [`new ArrayList<>(500*500)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)). This will avoid the overhead of growing the list dynamically.

Answer (score 6):

You are constructing 250000 instances of your Pix class. That will take some time.

Consider having a 2 dimensional array of booleans instead. Where false means the pixel is black.

You don't need to initialize the values yourself as they will default to false.

```
    boolean[][] pixs = new boolean[500][500];
```

You can iterate over the structure with this:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < 500; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 500; y++) {
            System.out.println(pixs[x][y]);
        }
    }
```

And you can set a particular pix with

```
    int x = 232;
    int y = 455;
    pixs[x][y] = true;
```